# Finding maximum CSV field sizes for large file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to determine maximum field sizes for a large CSV file (~5GB) with over 300 fields that I want to dump into a MySQL table. The CSV file schema I have for the file gives incorrect maximum field lengths, so I run into errors on the table import. I'm running Ruby 2.0 on Windows.

I'm using an array to store the maximum field lengths according to the field's index (or column) location, i.e. ignoring the fields actual name in the header. I've tried fancier things like using hashes, inject, and zip, etc, but it seems that a simple array works fastest here.

```
 field_lengths[0] = Max length of first field   
 field_lengths[1] = Max length of second field
 etc.
```

The file is too large to slurp at once or parse column-wise using CSV. So, I open the CSV file and use CSV#foreach to parse each line (ignoring the header using the :headers => true option). For each row, I loop through the parsed array of field values and compare the field's length with the current maximum length stored in the field_length array. I realize there are much easier ways to do this with smaller files. This method works OK for larger files, but I still haven't been able to make it to the end of my particular file using this method.

To get around not being able to finish the file, I currently define a number of lines to read including the header (=n), and break once I've reached the n-th line. In the example below, I read 101 lines from the CSV file. (1 header row + 100 actual data rows). I'm not sure how many total rows are in the file since the process hasn't finished.

```
 require 'csv'
 require 'pp'

 data_file = 'big_file.csv'

 # We're only reading the first 101 lines in this example
 n = 101
 field_lengths = []

 File.open(data_file) do |f|
   CSV.foreach(f, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |csv_row|
       break if $. > n
       csv_row.fields.each_with_index do |a,i|
           field_lengths[i] ||= a.to_s.length
           field_lengths[i] = a.to_s.length if field_lengths[i] < a.to_s.length
       end
   end
 end

 pp field_lengths
```

IO#read can read a certain number of bytes, but if I parse the file by bytes the records may get split. Does anyone have alternate suggestions for parsing the CSV file, by splitting it up into smaller files? O'Reilly's Ruby Cookbook (Lucas Carlson & Leonard Richardson, 2006, 1st ed), suggests breaking a large file into chunks (as below), but I'm not sure how to extend it to this example, particularly dealing with the line breaks etc.

```
 class File 
    def each_chunk(chunk_size = 1024)
        yield read(chunk_size) until eof?
    end
 end

 open("bigfile.txt") do |f|
    f.each_chunk(15) {|chunk| puts chunk}
 end
```

Comment: I would use the Unix `split` command rather than try to do everything in Ruby: http://kb.iu.edu/data/afar.html

Comment: @AlistairIsrael split wouldn't work on csv very well.

Comment: I'd use `split` only to split the large main file into multiple smaller files, using the `-l` option (number of lines). Say, from one 5GB file (with, say 5 million lines) into 100 files of 50,000 lines each. From then I'd use some kind of multi-threaded or multi-process map-reduce type implementation to find the longest columns.

Comment: Split won't work with csv though because it doesn't consider escaping with line breaks.

Comment: @pguardiario Ahh, I was assuming that the CSV would have C-style strings and not allow actual newline characters in fields. In that case, maybe a quick pass using [CSVfix](https://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) first?

Comment: There's really no point. It won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using CSV.foreach wrong, it takes a string for a filename:

```
field_lengths = {}

CSV.foreach(data_file, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |csv_row|
  csv_row.each do |k, v|
    field_lengths[k] = [field_lengths[k] || 0, v.length].max
  end
end

pp field_lengths
```

Comment: Thanks for point out the CSV.foreach correction. This hash solution is much more concise and it gives the field names also. I think v.length should be v.to_s.length in the event v is nil.

Comment: My file still seems to large with this method, though. Baron Schwartz of High Performance MySQL gives a solution using a perl script "...that reads lines out of the huge file and prints them to a fifo...Every million lines, the script prints an EOF character to the fifo, closes it and removes it, then re-creates it and keeps printing more lines. If you ‘cat’ the fifo file, you get a million lines at a time from it." http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/03/how-to-load-large-files-safely-into-innodb-with-load-data-infile/ Is it possible to implement a similar method with Ruby?

Comment: What does mysql have to do with csv?

Comment: I mentioned the article in reference to splitting the CSV into smaller chunks. MySQL is a coincidence.

Comment: I see. Splitting the file into smaller chunks won't make it faster though. I don't think anything will (except a faster computer).

Comment: Agreed. As far as the field lengths though, this works. Just need some patience!

Answer (score 0):

Given a CSV::Table in a variable called csv, you can change it to be "by column" and use collect or map...or inject.  There's lots of approaches.

e.g.

```
csv.by_col!
field_lengths = cols.map{|col| col.map{|r| r.is_a?(String) ? r.to_s.length : r.map{|v| v.to_s.length}.max }.max}
```

- The first map iterates through the columns.
- The second map iterates through the header (String) then the array of row values.
- So the third map iterates through the rows where you can convert the values into a string and return its length.
- The first max is the maximum value string length.
- The second max is the maximum between the header's lengths and the max value length.
- At the end, you may wish to return the csv to *col_or_row*

e.g.

```
csv.by_col_or_row!
```